# use a (Polymer) web component within a plugin (or theme)?

Tags: plugin-development

I've recently learned about [Web Components](https://www.webcomponents.org) (sorry I'm late, i'm not a pro developer :)) and, well, they are quite awesome.

For the plugin i'm coding, I need a menu exactly like this one, [@polymer/paper-menu-button](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-menu-button/demo/demo/index.html).

Since it already exists as a web component, which should I loose my time coding my own ? :)

- What I see is that a lot of people have been talking about them, but maybe the hype has fallen back ? (a lot of google entries were published in 2017, not so much today)
- I had a try (non-conclusive for now), did install the dependencies using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/), but well, it is 2.6 Mo of files for a... menu, which is a lot !  I also have to register several JS files in my plugin; which are still more files to load.

Well, I was wondering if it was a good practice to use web components in Wordpress development, and if you had advices or comments about that.

Thanks !

Comment: Something to consider, if you planned on using this for a WordPress menu, is that whatever time you saved scripting (or finding a regular JS script) you would need to spend to develop an entirely custom menu walker in PHP to output menus with the required markup.

Comment: I would save time, of course... But it will require dependencies, etc, and I don't see much entries about that topic on internet (WP + custom elements)